# Who is Patient X?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Right at the start of the Prologue, there are emails and articles about Patient X and how he can accept augs without rejection.  Are they referring to Adam?  He seems to fit the bill for this, but I thought he wasn't (noticeably?) augmented—so how would they know—until after the incident that kicks off the game.

So who is Patient X?

Comment: A quick search turned up this thread - http://uk.gamespot.com/pc/action/deus-ex-human-revolution/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-60188163&pid=944090. I don't know anything about the series so I can't comment on it's accuracy.

Comment: They don't need to augment him to take a tissue sample and run mad scientist experiments on it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You are -- later in the game Megan Reed confirms it, and you discover clues by doing the various sidequests. While you were an infant a corporation experimented on you and a few dozen other babies; you were the only one to survive the modifications and come through, but the scientists who worked on you caught a bad case of remorse and torched the place after smuggling you out.

Comment: Incidentally, the corporation referred to in the answer is Versalife. This will mean much more to people who played the first game.

Answer (score 3):

It is ...

> Adam Jensen.

Throughout the game there are several hints towards that possibility and near the end it is stated outright.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't finished the game (or looked at any other answer here), but it has to be…

> **Adam Jensen**. From the fact that he has zero need for neuropozine; he was genetically experimented on as an infant; the comment Sarif made in Jensen's appartment; and Megan's team only got the Patient X info when he was hired.